# Local development in VM for security reasons (MacOS)

Tags: macos, security, virtual-machine

Recently I heard that some npm packages are getting hacked (for example case with UA parser), which scared me a bit.

Is the problem serious, and should I consider using VM for local development?

If so, what are the best options to run macOS VM on Mac?

After a short research, I have found that there is an option to run MacOs VM in Parallels, how does it impact performance, is any better/simpler alternative?

Comment: Can you use docker ? which might be easier to setup than MacOS VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look on this threat from a formal perspective, then you can understand the **risk** (of being hacked by downloading a third party malicious library) as a composite made of **probability** (that an event occurs) and **damage** (what will you loose in case the risk materialises).

Both of them depend on your personal situation. Example: I have never created a separate VM for dev purposes while writing yet-another-spring-app in Java, but I have created a VM several times when testing some funky code supposed to create a "gold card" for my Android phone.

I would still say, that the probability of being hacked by a malicious third party dependence is still small when using mainstream libraries (in case of ua-parser-js the attack window was 4 hours long). The probability gets even lower when you hardcode the library version and cache them locally.